# Prototype tools for Virtual Reality

Tags: usability, user-centered-design, prototype, augmented-reality, virtual-reality

I appreciate it if anyone can share your real experience about this topic.
I already made paper prototypes and video concepts for this kind of project, but maybe someone already knows a particular tool for this type of project, something like a 'bootstrap' or 'adobe xd' for design Virtual Reality.

Comment: I suspect that, as this is about software requests, it will be put on hold but I'd also be interested to know if there are any tools out there.

Answer (score 1):

This [article about designing for VR](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2017/02/getting-started-with-vr-interface-design/) was posted to Smashing Magazine earlier this month. It describes a use case.

These were the tools they used:

> Before we get started with the walkthrough, here are the tools we’ll need:
>
> **Sketch**
>   We’ll use Sketch to design our interfaces and user flows. If you don’t have it, you can download a trial version. Sketch is our preferred interface design software, but if you’re more comfortable using Photoshop or anything else, that would work, too.
>
> **GoPro VR Player**
>   GoPro VR Player is a 360-degree content viewer. It’s provided by GoPro and is free. We’ll use it to preview our designs and test them in context.
>
> **Oculus Rift**
>   Hooking Oculus Rift into the GoPro VR Player will enable us to test the design in context.

Comment: Pretty good Paul!
I found this project about the process too:
https://www.artefactgroup.com/work/storyboard-vr/

Comment: @zed I just came across this http://webvrstudio.com/

Comment: Great! I will subscribe!